Is there any evidence to prove that Ramayan and Mahabharata are not Copied From Buddhist Jatakas. The Dashratha and Gatha Jatakas
I have seen many Buddhist claiming that Ramayana and Mahābhārata are copied from their Jatakas. Even Wikipedia says that Dashrata Jataka is oldest attested version of Ramayana.
Is there any evidence to prove that Ramayana AND Mahābhārata are nor copied from Buddhism and Are Pre Buddha.

Bauddha śāstras, including jātakas (which are contained within the Tripiṭakas), are not older than Śākyamuni Buddha, while Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa and Mahābhārata, were composed by Ṛṣi Vālmīki and Ṛṣi Vyāsa, both being contemporary to the time and majority of events in their respective itihāsa śāstras. Śākyamuni Buddha existed much later in the Kaliyuga (more than 1000 yrs after Janamejaya), and at Śākyamuni's time, Vyāsa's Mahābhārata and Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa were already existing.

Wikipedia is not a prāmāṇya source, nor is any Indologist (s) on this matter.
Also, a similar question, has already been asked Between Daśaratha-Jātaka and Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa which is older?

Dharmakīrti, a revered Bauddha ācārya, himself considered Vālmīki and Vyāsa as the authors of Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa and Mahābhārata, he has a famous short verse-
śailairbandhyati sma vānarahyatairvālmīkirambhonidhi
vyāsaḥ pārthaśaraistathāpi na tayoratyuktirudbhāvyate /
vāgarthau ca tulādhr̥tāviva tathāpyasmannibandhānayaṁ
loko dūṣayati prasāritamukhastubhyaṁ pratiṣṭhe namaḥ //

Transl. : Vālmīki dammed the sea with rocks
put into place by vānaras
and Vyāsa filled it with arrows shot by Pārtha,
yet neither is suspected of hyperbole.
On the other hand, I weigh both word and sense
and yet the public sneers and scorns my work
O Reputation, I salute you!

If somebody told you that the epics have been copied from the Buddhist jatakas, then that person is surely an Ambedkarite. These people, blinded by their hatred of everything related to brahmins & misguided by Ambedkar's faulty interpretation of Hinduism, cherry-pick certain facts to fit their propaganda. Hinduism interpreted by an Ambedkarite is as rejectable as that of Zakir Naik.

@Bingming even the Indological world widely accepts the two Ithihasas as the sources. Also unlike in Buddhist sources the amount written about Rama and Krishna not only the actual Ithihasas, but secondary literature proves by reason that only the Hindu account of the legend is true.

Regarding other sources argument: This answer is accepted as of now, as the correct answer. While the answer is very informative, it doesn't solve the problem.
The two early sources doesn't mention Ramayana and Mahabharata by name. It just says Itihasa which means history. This cannot be used to automatically mean Ramayana and Mahabharata as Hindus understand the word today, and therefore doesn't prove these Hindus epics existed before.

The third source does mention the epics by name, but it seems to be a very late version. Probably compiled after 5th century AD as per ChatGPT, as I couldn't find it on Wiki. And even then the author doesn't tell Lord Buddha learned Ramayana and Mahabharata, he is telling Lord Buddha performed similar miracles and then the author says he will teach Brahmins Vedas, Epics etc. This in no way proves that Ramayana and Mahabharata existed before Lord Buddha.

A rule of logic is 'Proofs lie in the assertion, not in the negation'. What is the proof - and not opinion - that they arose from Buddhist sources?

@Bingming what is Janamejaya's birthtime?

rAmAyaNa & mahAbhArata are mentioned as part of buddha's education in mahabuddhavamsa & lalitavistara sutra :

mahabuddhavamsa 2.1 ch.2 part 5 :
The Prince, a Bodhisatta, demonstrated his skill in archery not only in his last human existence as Prince Siddhattha, but also while he
was still in the early stages of Pāramīfulfilment, in his existence as
Prince Asadisa. Here follows a brief account of this episode:
While still fulfilling the Perfections, he was born in one of the existences as Prince Asadisa, the eldest son of King Brahmadatta of
the City of Vārāṇasī. When he attained the age of sixteen, he
proceeded to the University town of Takkasilā where under the
worldfamous teacher, Disāpāmokkha, he learned the three Vedas
together with the eighteen branches of learning to the highest stage
of perfection.
lalitavistara sutra 12.65 :
ajalakṣaṇe miśralakṣaṇe kauṭubheśvaralakṣaṇe nirghaṇṭe nigame purāṇe itihāse vede vyākaraṇe nirukte śikṣāyāṃ chandasvinyāṃ yajñakalpe jyotiṣe sāṃkhye yoge kriyākalpe vaiśike vaiśeṣike
arthavidyāyāṃ bārhaspatye āmbhirye āsurye mṛgapakṣirute hetuvidyāyāṃ
jalayantre madhūcchiṣṭakṛte sūcikarmaṇi vidalakarmaṇi patrachede
gandhayuktau - ityevamādyāsu sarvakarmakalāsu laukikādiṣu
divyamānuṣyakātikrāntāsu sarvatra bodhisattva eva viśiṣyate sma
analysis of horses, analysis of elephants, analysis of cattle, analysis of goats, analysis of sheep, analysis of dogs, ritual science
and its related lexicon, revealed scripture, ancient stories,
history, the Vedas, grammar, etymologies, phonetics, metrics and
composition, rules for conducting rituals, astrology, the Sāmkhya
philosophical system, the Yoga philosophical system, ceremonies, the
art of courtesans, the Vaiśeṣika philosophical system, economics,
ethics, hydraulics, knowledge of demigods, knowledge of game animals,
knowledge of bird sounds, logic, hydromechanics, beeswax crafts,
sewing, wickerwork, leaf cutting, and perfume making.

amogha­pāśa­kalpa­rāja, a bauddha tantra, makes reference to rAmAyaNa & mahAbhArata :

2.775 He then continually worked miracles and performed hundreds of thousands of magical feats as described in the
Mahābhārata. There is no doubt that it was because of the king of incense that Viṣṇu defeated the Pāṇḍavas.
2.866 "Regarding books on the subject of awakening, I will explain the doctrine, the rules of discipline, and the philosophy of
Mahāyāna. To brahmins, I will explain the Purāṇas, the Vedas, fire
oblation rituals, the Mahābhārata, and the Rāmāyaṇa.

Dashrata Jataka is part of pali canon but pali canon doesn't claim to be buddha's work. It calls itself as work of his followers who arrived in lanka in Parivāra 2.1  :

“Upāli and Dāsaka, Soṇaka and so Siggava; With Moggaliputta as the
fifth— These were in India, the land named after the glorious rose
apple.
Then Mahinda, Iṭṭiya, Uttiya and so Sambala; And the wise one named
Bhadda:
These mighty beings of great wisdom, Came here from India; They taught
the Collection on Monastic Law, In Sri Lanka.
And the five Collections of Discourses, And the seven works of
philosophy; Then Ariṭṭha the discerning, And the wise Tissadatta.

Thus rAmAyaNa & mahAbhArata existed at the time of buddha & Dashrata Jataka was a much later composition by buddha's disciples.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

pali canon text mahāniddesa catalogues the observances adopted by others to
propitiate gods where the gods listed are vāsudeva & baladeva - vāsudevavatikā vā honti, baladevavatikā vā honti, - here

It can be rationally proven that Ramayana and Mahabharata weren't copied from Buddhist Jataka and were the other way around. If you look at the extent of detail in the Ithihasas and their mere length, you can see a well-established tradition of worshipping these avatars of Vishnu. Not to mention their continual use in second-hand literature like Puranas. Buddha is also seen as an avatar of Vishnu, but before he came to be known as such he spouted his false Dharma known as Buddha Dharma as per Vishnu Purana. Therefore, the major core details of Buddha's life are seen within the Buddhist and not Hindu tradition. Essentially your claim is like me saying just because a small reference in the sacred Purana of Buddha's existence is mentioned, the Hindu tradition was the first to conceive of Buddha.
"Of heretics, or those who reject the authority of the Vedas: their origin, as described by Vaśiṣṭha to Bhīṣma: the gods, defeated by the Daityas, praise Viṣṇu: an illusory being, or Buddha, produced from his body."
--Chapter XVII - Of heretics, or those who reject the authority of the Vedas


Disclaimer: To give direct citations and a proper answer as expected by Hinduism SE, for this question is not easy, so I am going to make an internal logical argument in favor of the ancientness of Hindu Epics. This and similar type of questions seems more to be trying to shake the faith of Hindus in their religion than trying to make an honest historical argument. So I am going to address from that standpoint.
First I'm going to explain my opinion on this and then try to give a logical argument as to how to establish the ancientness of Hindu epics with Buddhists. As a Hindu, I have some unpopular beliefs, which are only my speculations and opinions and are not to be taken as the orthodox beliefs. This is more of sharing my opinion than an actual answer, as I feel there should be more discussions about this among Hindus

My Opinion:
I think Mahabharata War happened around 800-1000 BCE. And Ramayana happened around 600-800 years before Mahabharata, so around 1400-1800 BCE.
This is because:

there is the direct statement that there were 1,015 (or 1,050) years
between the birth of Parikshit (Arjuna's grandson) and the accession
of Mahapadma Nanda (400–329 BCE), which would yield an estimate of
about 1400 BCE for the Bharata battle. owever, this would imply
improbably long reigns on average for the kings listed in the
genealogies.Of the second kind is analysis of parallel genealogies in
the Puranas between the times of Adhisimakrishna (Parikshit's
great-grandson) and Mahapadma Nanda. Pargiter accordingly estimated 26
generations by averaging 10 different dynastic lists and, assuming 18
years for the average duration of a reign, arrived at an estimate of
850  BCE for Adhisimakrishna, and thus approximately 950  BCE for the
Bharata battle.
B. B. Lal used the same approach with a more conservative assumption
of the average reign to estimate a date of 836 BCE, and correlated
this with archaeological evidence from Painted Grey Ware (PGW) sites,
the association being strong between PGW artifacts and places
mentioned in the epic. John Keay confirms this and also gives 950 BCE
for the Bharata battle Source

And Ramayana happened around 600-800 years ago because, Brihadbala a descendant of Lord Sri Rama is mentioned in Mahabharata. He was 31 or 32 generation from Lord Rama. Assuming an average of 22 years per generation, it would be approximately 600-800 years.

Brihadbala is considered to be the last king of the line of Ikshvaku;
the dynasty spanned 31-32 generations between Rama and him.
Source

But both Ramayana and Mahabharatha were written much later, they were probably passed down orally from generation to generation and then added upon, exaggerated and then compiled into the currently available forms.
Mahabharata completion date maybe around 400 BCE to 200 AD

The bulk of the Mahābhārata was probably compiled between the 3rd
century BCE and the 3rd century CE, with the oldest preserved parts
not much older than around 400 BCE.[6][7] The text probably reached
its final form by the early Gupta period (c. 4th century CE) Source

And Ramayana:

The scholars' estimates for the earliest stage of the text ranging
from the 7th to 4th centuries BCE,[5][6] and later stages extending up
to the 3rd century CE Source


But Lord Buddha's time period is around 500 BCE, by then maybe Ramayana and Mahabharata were still not be compiled or widely circulated and may have remained in scholarly circles. Hindus were more oral tradition oriented so may have not felt the need to put it down on paper. So that is why we do not have very ancient manuscripts. This does not mean the epics were later created.

Logical Argument:
Instead of trying to prove whether Hindus copied Ramayana and Mahabharata from Buddhist Jataka tales, I think we can use their own claim against them and try to prove Ramayana and Mahabharata actually happened, there by some Hindus definitely would have seen and known the stories before Lord Buddha.
Assuming you are arguing with a believing Buddhist, you ask them the following simple question. "Do you believe Jataka tales are authentic works told by Lord Buddha himself?"
If they say no, then they themselves will have to say Jataka tales are fake and madeup and were not told by Lord Buddha. And they have to admit their own tradition has been lying.
If they say yes, then ask "Do you think Lord Buddha is a liar?"
If they say yes, even arguing that Lord Buddha could have lied for a good purpose, then they can't entirely  trust their own religion as the entire philosophy maybe a lie propounded by Lord Buddha.
If they say no, which probably any Buddhist would say, then the Jataka tales told by Lord Buddha should be considered real and true. So according to Buddhism itself Lord Buddha was born as Rama Pandita in Dashratha Jataka in one of his previous birth, so if Lord Buddha is saying truth then the story of Ramayana did really happen before Lord Buddha, which many Hindus would have seen and remembered and passed down to their descendants which eventually got compiled into Ramayana.
So according to Buddhist themselves Ramayana happened historically if we were to trust the words of Lord Buddha, so it cannot be a later invention, although  some parts may be added. Similar argument can be used for Mahabharata.

P. S:
Regarding other sources argument: This answer is accepted as of now, as the correct answer. While the answer is very informative, it doesn't solve the problem.
The two early sources doesn't mention Ramayana and Mahabharata by name. It just says Itihasa which means history. This cannot be used to automatically mean Ramayana and Mahabharata as Hindus understand the word today, and therefore doesn't prove these Hindus epics existed before.
The third source does mention the epics by name, but it seems to be a very late version. Probably compiled after 5th century AD as per ChatGPT, as I couldn't find it on Wiki. And even then the author doesn't tell Lord Buddha learned Ramayana and Mahabharata, he is telling Lord Buddha performed similar miracles and then the author says he will teach Brahmins Vedas, Epics etc. This in no way proves that Ramayana and Mahabharata existed before Lord Buddha.

Your answer is dubious on multiple levels. Historically, it is accepted that the Jatakas you mentioned were written much after Buddha's time. Indologists themselves widely agree that Mahabharata and Ramayana are true, so your historical angle is flawed. Also, if Buddha did write the Jataka tales by some chance he would be a liar as nowhere does it state in the Pali Canon the mention of Mahabharata and Ramayana, yet now he claims to be Rama and Krishna's brother.

Also, the question here isn't about the age of Buddha, but the originality of the Mahabharata and Ramayana. As I explained before, the length and in-depth detail of Mahabharata and Ramayana, unlike those portions of the Jatakas proves that they're the original teaching. I also cited how Vishnu Purana provides a small portion on Buddha, but not the extant of his life as found in Pali Canon, because to a Vaishnava and most Hindus Buddha came down to teach falsehood and that falsehood had to be taught before his avatar was revealed.

@Haridasa I don't think you understood my answer. Please read it again carefully. I'm not telling Ramayana and Mahabharata are not historical, I'm not telling Jataka tales are true and all of it was told by Lord Buddha himself. If you read carefully, I'm making an internal logical argument, Read " I am going to make an internal logical argument in favor of the ancientness of Hindu Epics." and " their own claim against them". This is first by assuming everything what the opponent says as true and then show an internal contradiction

@Haridasa that is why the argument asks them first, Assuming you are arguing with a believing Buddhist, you ask them the following simple question. "Do you believe Jataka tales are authentic works told by Lord Buddha himself?"
If they say no, then they themselves will have to say Jataka tales are fake and madeup and were not told by Lord Buddha. And they have to admit their own tradition has been lying.

@Haridasa please google what is circular reasoning and simple assertion is. You are doing it again and again, you are simply asserting "Mahabharata and Ramayana, unlike those portions of the Jatakas proves that they're the original teaching" ?? Where is the proof for this statement? I don't know what is the relevance of Vishnu Purana here?

@Haridasa your argument of pattern recognition is wrong, there is no rule which says if there are two scriptures with same story, one with short version and another with extensive version, smaller short stories should be considered as later one. In fact it is opposite to common sense, urban legends and stories start out small and then get more detailed and legendary, almost all mythology works like that. First normally we have a story and then it gets added on. Many stories are found in short form in Vedas and Upanishads, later expanded in Puranas.

@Haridasa Please continue in the chat room in one place https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/153436/discussion-between-haridasa-and-hari-kumar

From a Vedic view this is what is believed and again I used the Buddhist puranic story as an example. Also unless you can provide proof of the oldest Jataka with Rama or Krishan being older than Valmiki, then I disagree. Also, even then the evidence is shaky as Buddhist were more well known to create schools and monasteries to preserve records than Hindus. So, both your points can be refuted with ease and since the Vedic tradition is more oral that's another thing to consider. Lastly, the Pali Cannon which is Buddha's teachings never mentions Rama and Krishna.

It can be clearly seen that Buddha had no knowledge of Rama or Krishna nor did Buddhist give the same level of appreciation to such divine figures that we Hindus gave.

@Haridasa please reply the same in chat room and not here

@Haridasa I have replied to you in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/153436/discussion-between-haridasa-and-hari-kumar

Also many Hindu text are lost to time many of the newer versions may stem back a lot older we just haven't found them. For example, the most recent Vedic manuscript is 10 BCE, but is believed to stem back 2000 BCE and many of the deities in Rg Veda have clear and well established parallels to Rama and Krishna. So disassociating the two from Vedic literature is also wrong.

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35088/16165
